# Kotlin idiomatic way to round up integer division

Tags: kotlin

If the remainder of an integer division is not zero, I want to proceed with the result rounded up.

Examples:

- `5 / 2` yields `2`. But I want to move on with `3` (integer).
- `4 / 2` yields `2`, which is fine for my use case.

I currently resort to this clunky construct:

```kotlin
ceil(5 / 2.toDouble()).toInt()
```

example on Kotlin playground: https://pl.kotl.in/eX0rYXnsH

Is there a more idiomatic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is missing is `ceilDiv`. Although whether std lib should implement that is still [(in discussion)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-54264), we could implement with the help of [`floorDiv`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/floor-div.html):

```kotlin
/** Divides this value by the other value, ceiling the result to an integer that is closer to positive infinity. */
fun Int.ceilDiv(other: Int): Int {
    return this.floorDiv(other) + this.rem(other).sign.absoluteValue
}
```

```kotlin
fun main() {
    println((-2).ceilDiv(2)) // -1
    println((-1).ceilDiv(2)) // 0
    println(0.ceilDiv(2)) // 0
    println(1.ceilDiv(2)) // 1
    println(2.ceilDiv(2)) // 1
    println(3.ceilDiv(2)) // 2
    println(4.ceilDiv(2)) // 2
    println("-----")
    println((-2).ceilDiv(-2)) // 1
    println((-1).ceilDiv(-2)) // 1
    println(0.ceilDiv(-2)) // 0
    println(1.ceilDiv(-2)) // 0
    println(2.ceilDiv(-2)) // -1
    println(3.ceilDiv(-2)) // -1
    println(4.ceilDiv(-2)) // -2
}
```

Comment: This answer is not really correct, it works properly only if divisor is 2 or -2. `2.ceilDiv(1)` gives... 3. `7.ceilDiv(3)` gives 2. We can't simulate ceiling operation by adding 1/-1, but by adding (divisor - 1). Using your way of handling negative numbers, the correct answer could be something like: `(this + other - other.sign).floorDiv(other)`, but that requires additional testing.

Comment: @broot, thanks a lot for pointing out. Fixed with `rem`, as `this + other - other.sign` might overflow.

Comment: + style points if you make it an `infix fun`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid double conversion <-> int casting (which I think is what your concern is) you can try using `div` and `rem`

```
val dividend = 5
val divisor = 3

dividend.div(divisor) + if (dividend.rem(divisor) > 0) 1 else 0
```

Comment: Your if/else can be replaced with the `sign` function or property. `result = dividend / divisor + sign(dividend % divisor)`